# Angular 7: Inject and use Services globally for all Components

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pretty new to the Angular world. I have been using React and Vue JS, and now I need to work with Angular 7. So, I'm trying to understand/organize the project architecture.

I'm using the following Services imports in a lot of app components, and am generating a lot of duplicated lines:

```
// Services
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LoadingService } from '@services/loading/loading';
import { ErrorService } from '@services/error';


constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private loading: LoadingService,
    private errorService: ErrorService,
) {}
```

Is there any way to Inject some services globally to use throughout the app in order to make the component's code cleaner?

Thanks,
Mauricio.

Comment: In order to use a service inside a component you have to use the `DependecyInjection`. By its meaning, even tho is a singleton, you have to inject it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: while what you want would reduce the amount of imports in the component, it would make unit testing more difficult as you need to worry about globally available services. Unit of work pattern can be used as [cory-grinstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8594080/cory-grinstead) suggested.

Answer (score 3):

A common Dependency injection pattern would be to create a common service that has all of these services, then inject that common service into all of the ones you want. This way you only have to maintain those common dependencies in one service.

Angular also provides module level injectables using the `@NgModule`
https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule

Answer (score 0):

I would personally advise you to keep using dependency injection as it is a clear indication of all the dependencies that a component has, but if you still want to go that road you could use a static class that would hold the instances you care about.

e.g.

```
export class GlobalInstances {
    public static translateService: TranslateService,
    public static loading: LoadingService,
    public static errorService: ErrorService,   
}
```

This can be easily referenced by any of your components and can be initialised by your main module (or any other module) using the APP_INITIALIZER token as the following example

```
export function initialiseGlobalDependencies(translateService: TranslateService, loadingService: LoadingService, errorService: ErrorService): () => Promise<any> {
    GlobalInstances.translateService = translateService;
    GlobalInstances.loadingService = loadingService;
    GlobalInstances.errorService = errorService;
    return () => Promise.resolve(true);
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ],
    imports: [ ],
    providers: [
        { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initialiseGlobalDependencies, multi: true, deps: [TranslateService, LoadingService,ErrorService] },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```